# Extract currency symbol from currency code Yii

Tags: yii, currency

Is there a way we can get the currency symbol from the currency code using some inbuilt formatter in Yii ?
For eg, I pass 'USD' to the function and it returns the dollar symbol ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
echo Yii::app()->numberFormatter->formatCurrency(56, 'USD');
```

where 56 is the cost.

More specific information can be found in the [yii reference documentatio](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberFormatter)n.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I already tried this,I know that it does work fine for USD.
However when I try the same for INR - the Indian equivalent, it returns 'â‚¹' instead of 'Rs' . Where am I going wrong ? Tried with $locale->getCurrencySymbol as well but to no avail.

Comment: @RohanReddy, What's your language config in config file? And check in yii framework folder's i18n/data/<your local>.php file's currncySymbol that correct symbol exists.